# How to sync ExoPlayer library in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

My app crashed when it comes to sync ExoPlayer library. At first, it crashes when I had Android Studio 3.6 and for no reason it gave me following errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65DVg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lOgy.png)

but recently I updated Android Studio to 4.0 so I can sync ExoPlayer libraries and no problem when running app

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.11.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.4'
```

but when I add XML code as you see in the following

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and run my app it crashes and gives me the following error:

```
2020-05-30 12:39:59.271 18182-18182/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process 
is Whitelisted
2020-05-30 12:39:59.271 18182-18182/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2020-05-30 12:39:59.271 18182-18182/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - 
/data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2020-05-30 12:40:00.364 18182-18182/com.example.myapplication A/libc: Fatal 
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 
1, fault addr 0xb5a9f98 in tid 18182 (e.myapplication), pid 18182 
(e.myapplication)
```

Comment: Please do not include screenshots in your question, you have to copy the error log itself instead of including screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Sure you are implemented all below steps :

**1- Add repositories:**

you should add add these repos exactly with writted order. (buld.gradle:project)

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**2- Add ExoPlayer full module dependency**

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.4'
```

**3- Turn on Java 8 support (buld.gradle - module:app)**

```
  android{
     ...
    compileOptions {
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
 }
```

Comment: with a minor change it worked(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 needed to be implemented in compileOptions{...})
thanks a lot.

Comment: Your welcome, so if that was useful please check it as answered.

Comment: Google has decided to sunset `jcenter` in 2021, so what now?

Comment: @HankChan thanks for reminding me, use mavenCentral() Instead

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on @Yasin's answer.

With Google's decision to sunset `jcenter` in 2022, you might run into another problem - that is your current old version of **ExoPlayer** is only provided on `jcenter` but not on `google`. So I would suggest you to migrate to latest version of **ExoPlayer**, i.e. `v15`, as soon as possible - which is guaranteed to be found on `google`.